# jQuery.serialScroll - cant get it working

Tags: jquery, plugins, scroll

I'm trying to make horizontal scrolling news page. I have my news display in this structure:

```
<div id="news-container">
  <div id="news-wrapper">
    <div id="news">
      Some news content goes here
    </div>
    <div id="news">
      Some second news content goes here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm adding CSS below to make this all horizontal (I'm calculating #news wrapper width with jQuery so all the news items fits it):

```
#news-container {
    overflow: hidden;
}
#news {
    width: 350px;
    display: inline-table;
}
```

Now I've been trying to add some next/prev buttons with jQuery and use serialScroll on them but have no idea how to get it working! I've added buttons (no CSS on them, ill get to it when they will work):

```
<img class="prev" src="img/prev.gif" alt="prev" width="42" height="53" />
<img class="next" src="img/next.gif" alt="next" width="42" height="53" />
```

And this is js copied and modified from some SerialScroll plugin examples. I have no idea how to make it working and how to attach any actions to my buttons (tried with .click() and some trigger options from plugin but without effect)

```
$("#news-container").serialScroll({
  target:'#news-container',
  items:'div',
  prev:'#prev',
  next:'#next',
  axis:'xy',
  navigation:'a',
  duration:700,
  force:true,
})
```

@edit:
This is demo I've been relating to:
http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/serialScroll/

Comment: can you give a link to a working demo or at least the plugin site?  Also, did you include the plugin on your page?

Comment: @Joseph Yeah, I've included it. I've edited post by adding link to the demo.

Answer (score 0):

well for starters, `$(#news-container)` needs to be `$("#news-container")`

Answer (score 0):

Either change `<img class="prev" ...` to `<img id="prev" ...` for both images or
change

```
  prev:'#prev',
  next:'#next',
```

to

```
  prev:'.prev',
  next:'.next',
```

Comment: I'm kinda surprised I didn't noticed this mistake, thank You. But still, it does not working at all ;/

Comment: @smogg unfortunately I can't say much more without the source code :(  It could be a number of things

Comment: You need source of what? Plugin or my site? I gave you 99% of my code, there is nothing more on my website yet ;) Here is link plugin website: http://flesler.blogspot.com/2008/02/jqueryserialscroll.html and its link to project on jQuery site:
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/SerialScroll